# Return all the rows in a group

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sum

Is there a way of getting all the rows used in a group?

As you would expect, the query below only returns one row per `custref`.  But if `totalamount` is > 0, I want it to return all the rows in the group.  Otherwise none.

```
$sql = "SELECT
    debtors.custref,
    debtors.amount,
    users.bnkSort,
    users.bnkAccNum,
    users.bnkAccName,
    SUM(debtors.amount) AS totalamount
    FROM debtors
    LEFT JOIN users ON debtors.custref=users.custref
    WHERE
    users.bank = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY debtors.custref
";
```

Comment: The `GROUP BY` clause is for executing functions over groups of data, if you want the rows in each group, then you need to issue a different query. BTW you shouldn't `SELECT` columns that are not part of the aggregation, because that would lead incorrect results (although MySQL will accept that).

Comment: Check out [group_concat()](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/), which would allow you to take detail items from a particular column and concat them into one value along with the grouped on value(s).

Answer (score 1):

Your query has multiple columns that are invalidated by the `group by` -- columns that are not the same in rows in the group. Also, the `where` clause is undoing the `left join`.  So, this is basically your query:

```
SELECT d.custref, SUM(d.amount) AS totalamount
FROM debtors d JOIN 
     users u
     ON d.custref = u.custref
WHERE u.bank = 'Yes'
GROUP BY d.custref;
```

To get all the fields, you can use this as a subquery:

```
SELECT d.*, u.*
FROM (SELECT d.custref, SUM(d.amount) AS totalamount
      FROM debtors d JOIN 
           users u
           ON d.custref = u.custref
      WHERE u.bank = 'Yes'
      GROUP BY d.custref
      HAVING totalamount > 0
     ) dc JOIN
     debtors d
     ON dc.custref = d.custref JOIN
     users u
WHERE u.bank = 'Yes';

 ON dc.custref = u.custref
```